# How to use already deployed erc20 token in another smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

I have successfully created and deployed an ERC20 Token.
Now I would like to create a smart contract that takes the already deployed token from user to become user of system.

In simple words: what I want to build is, user needs to pay certain amount of that token upon registration. on user's side, when user registers, it will open Metamask for the user and user needs to complete the transaction in order to successfully register on our platform.

So I would like to call transfer token from user using new smart contract and tokens are transferred to my account

I am a beginner as far as solidity programming is concerned and would like to get help from you guys here. I searched for similar answers but found none to be successful.

I have tried doing this:

*

```
function setA_Signature(uint _val) public returns(bool success){
    bool ab = dc.call(bytes4(keccak256("transfer(address, uint256)")),0x05cd32f08CcB230bfEfAd6eb5d0A0b294076AcD5,_val);
    return ab;
}

Deployed(0x4a72b5BFA05A7022912FD441583D92b995782743).transfer(_to, _val);
```

*

That's the error when I try to test call the function of a contract using etherscan.

[image: error]

Comment: Can you explain your source code? What are those addresses? A contract doesn't act in behalf of a user when making a transfer, the token when invoked by transfer will receive msg.sender equal to your contract. The error seems in the connection between etherscan and your wallet.

Comment: I want to just transfer already deployed  token from another smart contract or call transfer method of deployed contract from a new smart contract function.

Comment: Who is the owner of the tokens you want to transfer?

Comment: I am working on ropsten  
Contract address of the token: 0x4a72b5BFA05A7022912FD441583D92b995782743  

owner/creator address: 0x6b15245818cc9d18cc7fdee111b6e6d87ce37687  


0x05cd32f08CcB230bfEfAd6eb5d0A0b294076AcD5  
holder address who wants to become member by sending token to new smart contract

Comment: Sorry, the snippet of code and addresses provided are not enough to give an answer. What is dc? Who calls setA_Signature? What is Deployed? A contract by itself cannot transfer tokens that belong to someone else, they have to transfer tokens to the contract previously.

Comment: I have a token smart contract on eth ropsten testnet, now I want to create other smart contract that enables staking for the holders, the staking contract asks users to send their token to a given address to be unlocked after certain period of time (1 year or so). I want to interact with the token smart contract at ropsten from the new staking smart contract/
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4b96be51253856e20420a75d5ceb31ccf7623f90


I need a smart contract function which is able to call transfer function of token and transfer my token to one particular address of our organization

Comment: Sorry but without the code there's no way to analyze what's the problem. I'll repeat again, from the little details you shared, what "might" be the issue: a contract A cannot make transfers of tokens from another address B by itself. To allow A transfers B's tokens B has to approve A to do so (B has to call approve).